# firefoxProfileTemplate doesn't prevent certificate prompt in Mozilla

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am running Selenium Server.  I'm also launching an automated test script that I exported from the Mozilla Selenium IDE and exported to my Java client driver program which I compiled and ran in Eclipse using JUnit 4.8.  Two windows start up in Mozilla (since I'm using the "*chrome"/Firefox argument when instantiating my browser window object from the Java program).  One window looks like it contains logging information of some kind, and the other window is the actual automated test browser window.

**Here's how I'm starting the Selenium Server.**

cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\Selenium

java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc3.jar -interactive  -firefoxProfileTemplate  "C:\Users[Windows-Login]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\lcllklng.default"

The server starts up fine.  The reason I put the -firefoxProfileTemplate attribute into the start-up command because I kept getting the untrusted certificate in Mozilla.  I guess this is supposed to default my Windows login Mozilla profile.  However, it didn't work.  I have to click through the prompts each time I run my test cases.  **Is there a way to make it avoid the untrusted certificate?**  Could it be because I'm running Windows 7?

You'd also be my hero if you can help me avoid this for IE, Google Chrome and Safari.  But only if you feel helpful today.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the path you have given the default profile path?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be.<br />

The following folder has a "profiles.ini"<br />
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox<br />

It looks like this:<br />
----------------------------------<br />
[General]<br />
StartWithLastProfile=1<br />
<br />
[Profile0]<br />
Name=default<br />
IsRelative=1<br />
Path=Profiles/lcllklng.default<br />
----------------------------------<br />
<br />
And there's only one folder in here.<br />
C:\Users\wanta\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles<br />

Comment: I noticed a couple strange things yesterday.... 

My co-workers are able to get into the Mozilla Firefox profile manager by following this:
(and also by verifying the path matches the path of Mozilla on their machine)
http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2011/02/04/how-to-install-run-multiple-firefox-versions-in-windows-simultaneously/

Comment: However, when I type in that command in Windows 7, I get a new browser window instance of Mozilla Firefox (3.6) to popup, but not the Profile Manager.  That seemed strange.  The difference is that my Mozilla Firefox folder is installed in the "Program Files (x86)" folder, not the "Program Files" (aka 64 bit) folder.  Whenever I install, it always defaults to x86 for some reason even though I have a 64 bit machine.  This may be completely off tangent, but it's something I noticed.

Comment: When I go into Mozilla Firefox, via the JUnit launched window, I don't see my "wanta" (default) profile certificates.  But when I go in manually, I do.  So it's obviously getting the profile to see those.

Comment: I also verified that all my Mozilla Firefox processes were killed in Task Manager.  I even logged out of Windows and logged back in to make sure everything was in a vanilla state.

Comment: Somethings making me think that it has something to do with me not being able to edit the profile manager by typing in that command from the link I placed above.  And that is exactly what the firefoxProfileTemplate command argument is doing.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Close all your firefox browsers first. Then go to run and type firefox -P. You will get the profile manager

Comment: I will test this out when I get time.  It looks promising!

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391387/suppress-ssl-security-warning-in-firefox-when-using-selenium-for-automation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391387/suppress-ssl-security-warning-in-firefox-when-using-selenium-for-automation

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391387/suppress-ssl-security-warning-in-firefox-when-using-selenium-for-automation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391387/suppress-ssl-security-warning-in-firefox-when-using-selenium-for-automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to WebDriver to avoid this.